# Proof, Golden Ratio and Fibonacci

Tags: alternative-proof

I discovered a very interesting thing recently, and proved it by induction.

I found that the $n$th power of $\phi={1+\sqrt5 \over2}$, the Golden Ratio, is the product of $\phi$ with the $n$th Fibonacci number added to the $(n-1)$th Fibonacci number.

However, I'm not able to prove it by any other method. Can anyone help?

---

$\text{Theorem}:\; \phi^n=F_n\phi+F_{n-1}\qquad[F_0=0]$

$\text{Proof}:$

$\text{Trivial for }n=1.$

$\text{Let this be true for all }n\text{ till }k.$

$\text{Then,}$

$\begin{align}\phi^{k+1}&=\phi^k\phi\\&=(F_n\phi+F_{n-1})\phi\\&=F_n\phi^2+F_{n-1}\phi\\&=F_n(\phi+1)+F_{n-1}\phi\\&=F_n\phi+F_{n-1}\phi+F_n\\&=(F_n+F_{n-1})\phi+F_n\\&=F_{n+1}\phi+F_{(n+1)-1}\end{align}$

$\text{Therefore Proved by Induction Hypothesis}.$

---

So, is there an alternative proof? I tried taking $\phi^2=\phi+1$ and branching outwards, but got nowhere.

Comment: Actually this is an obvious result if you know the explicit expression for $F_n$.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Please elucidate.

Comment: Good work discovering this.  Along the same lines, you might want to read about [Binet's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula)

Comment: See Binet's formula for Fibbonacci numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fibonacci number can be defined using the recurrence relation
$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$
with $$F_0=0,F_1=1$$

Solving the relation will give
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}(\phi^n-\varphi^n)$$

where $$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},\varphi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$$

You can use this expression to prove your finding.

---

\begin{align}
F_n\phi+F_{n-1}=&=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^n-\varphi^n\right)\phi+\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n-1}-\varphi^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n+1}+\phi^{n-1}-\phi\varphi^n-\varphi^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n+1}+\phi^{n-1}-\phi\varphi\varphi^{n-1}-\varphi^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n+1}+\phi^{n-1}\underbrace{-\left(-1\right)\varphi^{n-1}-\varphi^{n-1}}_{=0}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi^{n+1}+\phi^{n-1}\right)\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt5}\left(\phi+\frac{1}{\phi}\right)\\
&=\frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt5}\left(\sqrt5\right)\\
&=\phi^n
\end{align}